# Output value from array (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
function getById($id) {
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `ids` WHERE `id` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($id)."'") or die($mysqli->error);
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

How do I get the value of id field?

```
$data = getById(1);
```

`echo $data[0]` or `echo $data['id']` doesn't work.

Comment: try to print $rows in function you will come to know what/ how it is returning the value

Comment: try to execute `var_dump($data)` to see what the function returns you.

Comment: `echo 1;` Because the value of `'id'` for `getById(1)` should be `1`.

Answer (score 4):

Your function returns an array of arrays, so to get the first ID:

```
$data = getById(1);
echo $data[0]['id'];
```

Side notes:

- Globals are undesirable. Consider passing the database connection object to the function as an argument instead.
- Escaping like that is a primitive way of preventing SQL Injection. The use of a [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) would be more secure and easier.
- `or die(....)` is bad practice because it exposes the detailed MySQL error to users, and it's hard to remove if you have written that hundreds of times. An alternative is `trigger_error()` which silently writes to your error log.

Answer (score 2):

You no need to use while and array. Get single row and you can get without using array:

```
function getById($id) {
    global $mysqli;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `ids` WHERE `id` = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($id)."'") or die($mysqli->error);

    return $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

$data = getById(1);

echo $data['id'];
```